# Boost libraries compilation fails

Tags: server, software-installation, libraries, boost

I am trying to install boost libraries 1.49.0 on a machine running ubuntu server 14.04. The compilation of boost fails with the following errors.

```
...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/locale/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/threading-multi/icu/formatter.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/locale/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_locale.a(clean) for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/locale/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/threading-multi>icu/formatter.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/locale/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_locale.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/locale/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/threading-multi>icu/formatter.o...
...skipped <p/usr/local/lib>libboost_locale.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/locale/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_locale.a...
...failed updating 2 targets...
...skipped 6 targets...
```

boost 1.49 is a requirement. Need help.

Comment: How  did you install the boost package(s) ? Are you sure they are in the lib path ?

Comment: I have not yet finished boost installation. This problem is caused during installation.
I am using the following commands to compile and install the boost 1.49. 
~$: ./bootstrap.sh -with-libraries=all
~$: sudo ./b2 install

Comment: It seems the mutli-thread part of the library is missing. Maybe it's a separate package you need to download.